# Browser caching for Wordpress site in shared hosting

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, caching, w3-total-cache

I have a site running under Wordpress 4.1.1. [This](http://dynamotechnology.com) is the live site. I'm trying to get the highest score at PageSpeed Insights from Google. One of the issues I'm getting in the report is:

```
Leverage browser caching
Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.

Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:

http://connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js?ver=4.1.1 (20 minutes)
http://platform.twitter.com/…=O1TZPrUbWI8cZSAGqTb6v5PaU&v=1&ver=4.1.1 (30 minutes)
https://apis.google.com/js/api.js (30 minutes)
https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js (30 minutes)
https://oauth.googleusercontent.com/…e:rpc:shindig.random:shindig.sha1.js?c=2 (60 minutes)
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
http://dynamotechnology.com/…ssets/min-css/ultimate.min.css?ver=3.9.4 (24 hours)
http://dynamotechnology.com/…/min-js/ultimate-params.min.js?ver=3.9.4 (24 hours)
http://dynamotechnology.com/…e_VC_Addons/assets/slick/ajax-loader.gif (24 hours)
http://dynamotechnology.com/…plus/css/comments-specific.css?ver=4.1.1 (24 hours)
http://dynamotechnology.com/…comments-plus/css/comments.css?ver=4.1.1 (24 hours)
http://dynamotechnology.com/…s/comments-plus/js/comments.js?ver=4.1.1 (24 hours)
http://dynamotechnology.com/…s/comments-plus/js/facebook.js?ver=4.1.1 (24 hours)

.....
```

For WP this is the `.htaccess` file I have on my hosting (Bluehost):

```
# Use PHP54CGI as default
AddHandler fcgid54-script .php

# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache

# START PageSpeed
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
   ModPagespeed off

   ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images,inline_images,recompress_images,convert_jpeg_to_progressive,recompress_jpeg,recompress_png,strip_image_meta_data,resize_images
   ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript,rewrite_css,make_google_analytics_async,remove_comments,collapse_whitespace

   ModPagespeedUseExperimentalJsMinifier on
</IfModule>
# END PageSpeed
```

Why cache isn't enabled? I have also installed W3 Total Cache plugin. Any advice? What I am doing wrong? How I can cache external resources? That can be done? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding expires rules on your `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN EXPIRES
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES
```

For external resources (Google, Facebook, ...) there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Excellent, that works, did you know any rule for compress or minify JS and CSS or any W3 Total Cache config for this? I'm in a shared hosting also